# Set the same font in QGIS legend as in map

Tags: qgis, legend, font, qgis-print-layouts

I want to use the same fonts in the legend that are used on the map (different feature = different font). Is it possible? I only get one font for all items.

Comment: I don't think it's possible right now. A workaround would be to delete legend text and use label objects for each legend entry.

Comment: Or create a separate legend for each entry.

Comment: Thank you for the approaches, I will try them tomorrow!